# Hiding Picklist Value based on profile or permission set

Tags: profile, case, permission-sets

Is it possible to hide a pick list value for a set of users ?
Can permission or profile set be used for this purpose ?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this (by profile) with Apex and Visualforce, but if you want to use native capabilities you can do this with RecordTypes.  you can have different pick-list values based on recordTypes and then have different users assigned different recordTypes based on their profile.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en

Comment: If you hide picklist values according to Record Type, all users will still see the same set of picklist values, unless the record itself is changed to a different Record Type. And in that case, the current picklist value will be preserved after the changeover.

Comment: You are correct there would need to be some data manipulation if trying to do this with historical records.